# Creating a network undirected weighted graph from a binary image for a minimum spanning tree

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to create a minimum spanning tree between pixels in a thresholded image of a crack.  The pixels do not always touch when I remove noise so I am trying to connect them in a graph.

Python 2.7 I have thresholded an image so everything that is below a threshold shows up white, all else is black.  I thresholded a 65x65 window at a time and set any window with less than 10 pixels to white.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import Image
import matplotlib
from cv2 import *

img=imread("IMG_1188.jpg")
gray = cvtColor(img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

threshold=35

width,height = gray.shape

for j in range( 0, height,65 ):
    for i in range( 0, width,65 ):

    gray[i:i+65,j:j+65]=inRange(gray[i:i+65,j:j+65],np.array([0]), np.array([35]))

    if np.sum(gray[i:i+65,j:j+65])<(2550):

        gray[i:i+65,j:j+65]=[0]
```

I created a dict to hold all the x,y pos of the white pixels and created nodes in networkx.

```
pos={}
k=int(0)
G =nx.Graph()
for j in range( 0, height):
    for i in range( 0, width):
        if np.array(gray[i,j])>np.array(0):
            gray[i,j]=255
            pos[k]=(int(i),int(j))
            G.add_node(pos[k])          
            k=k+1
```

I then checked every euclidean distance between each node and draw an edge if it is below a certain pixel distance (say 40).

```
k=1
for j in range (0,pos.len()):

    for i in range (k,pos.len()):   

        if np.sqrt(np.square(pos[i][0]-pos[j][0])+np.square(pos[i][1]-pos[j][1]))<=40:  
            G.add_edge(pos[i],pos[j],weight=(np.sqrt(np.square(pos[i][0]-pos[j][0])+np.square(pos[i][1]-pos[j][1]))))

    k=k+1
```

When I run the program it tells me there is no position for the node. (I've run it with different parameters and received different error nodes)

```
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Node (814, 700) has no position.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there something else happening between the 2nd and 3rd code snippets? in the 2nd `pos` is a dictionary, but in the 3rd part, pos is a data type with a `len()` method, which dicts do not have.

Comment: I found the root problem below, and I changed pos.len() to len(pos) without issues.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was referencing the x position of the nodes that were within 40 as the start of the edge

```
G.add_edge(pos[i],pos[j],weight=(np.sqrt(np.square(pos[i][0]-pos[j][0])+np.square(pos[i][1]-pos[j][1]))))
```

Instead I needed to reference the actual node identifier (I also used absolute value since it is one operation vs the squaring and square root)

```
G.add_edge(i,j,weight=(np.fabs(window1[i][0]-window1[j][0])+np.fabs(window1[i][1]-window1[j][1])))
```

Also I have found that I should use a K-D tree to speed up my code, as this code for 15000 points took 50 min or so.